# Dynamically add and update dropdown-select menu (error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I hope this code helps people trying to do the same thing however, I've got a small bug I need help with.

I have a button in my dropdown menu that opens a modal to add a new item to the database (then into the dropdown menu). My code successfully adds the item however, the 'add' button then disappears.

Before adding:

[image]

After adding:

[image]

HTML:

```
<!--Journal-->
    <li>
        <div class="pt-3 pb-0 px-4" id="journal">
            <select class="dropdown-select mt-0 journals_dropdown" id="journals_dropdown" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
            </select>
            <button class="btn-save btn btn-primary btn-sm add_journal_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_journal_modal">Add</button>
        </div>
    </li>
<!--/Journal-->
```

JS:

```
//===== Fill Journals Dropdown =====
function fill_journals() {
    $('#journals_dropdown').empty();

    //add items to dropdown
    for (var i=0; i<journals.length; i++) {
        $('#journals_dropdown').append($('<option></option>').val(journals[i]._id).html(journals[i].journal_name));
    }
    //$('#journal').append('<button class="btn-save btn btn-primary btn-sm add_journal_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_journal_modal">Add</button>');

    //select latest item from dropdown
    if(localStorage.getItem('latest_journal').length > 15) {
        $("#journals_dropdown").val(localStorage.getItem('latest_journal')).attr("selected","selected");
    }

}
```

The error is coming from this code in the JS (if I comment it out, the button doesn't disappear):

```
    //add items to dropdown
    for (var i=0; i<journals.length; i++) {
        $('#journals_dropdown').append($('<option></option>').val(journals[i]._id).html(journals[i].journal_name));
    }
```

PS. If I refresh the page, the fill_journals() works like a charm. I am trying to call it once the add new journal form is submitted like this;

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/add_journal',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (response) {
        $('#add_journal_modal').modal('toggle');
        localStorage.setItem("latest_journal", response);
        initialize();   //fill_journals() is part of this
        // location.reload();
    }
});
```